# combine two column of type array using pandas and encode dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

there are two column type array o/p is combine of col1 and col2 and encoded like this

```
    col1       col2        
0  [a,b,f]     [c,d,e]     
1  [c,d]       [a,b,e,f]   
2  [a]         [b,c,d,e,f]
```

o/p

```
    col1       col2          a    b    c    d    e    f
0  [a,b,f]     [c,d,e]       1    1    0    0    0    1
1  [c,d]       [a,b,e,f]     0    0    1    1    0    0
2  [a]         [b,c,d,e,f]   1    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['col1'].explode()).groupby(level=0).sum()], axis =1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
        col1             col2  a  b  c  d  f
0  [a, b, f]        [c, d, e]  1  1  0  0  1
1     [c, d]     [a, b, e, f]  0  0  1  1  0
2        [a]  [b, c, d, e, f]  1  0  0  0  0
```

##### Updated Answer with a complete working example:

```
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: ['a', 'b', 'f'], 1: ['c', 'd'], 2: ['a']},
                   'col2': {0: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
                            1: ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'],
                            2: ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']}})


dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['col1'].explode())
dummies = dummies.T.reindex(np.unique(np.concatenate((df['col1'].explode(
).unique(), df['col2'].explode().unique())))).T.fillna(0).groupby(level=0).sum()
df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
        col1             col2  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  [a, b, f]        [c, d, e]  1  1  0  0  0  1
1     [c, d]     [a, b, e, f]  0  0  1  1  0  0
2        [a]  [b, c, d, e, f]  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: 'e' column is missing

Comment: thank you , can we store  0, 1 instead 0.0 or 1.0

Comment: Yup use `df = df.convert_dtypes()`

Comment: @SandeepAgrawal because it's considering the value in `col1/col2` as string type. You can use `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` in these columns 1st. `df.col1 = df.col1.apply(eval)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the columns from the arrays in `col1` and  `col2` you can first find out the unique values for the columns and then fill the new columns with the values you want (`1` or `0` or whatever).

```
cols = df['col1'].explode().append(df['col2'].explode()).unique()
cols.sort()  # if you want your columns sorted

for col in cols:
    for ind, row in df.iterrows():
        if col in row[0]:
            df.loc[ind, col] = 1
        elif col in row[1]:  # use 'else' if the missing data is also 0
            df.loc[ind, col] = 0
```

Output:

```
        col1             col2    a    b    c    d    e    f
0  [a, b, f]        [c, d, e]  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1     [c, d]     [a, b, e, f]  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
2        [a]  [b, c, d, e, f]  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```